# copy constructor and overloaded '=' operator not working

Tags: c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

The copy constructor and overloaded '=' operator are not being called when assigned with result of sum of two class objects. There are working properly  when initialized and assigned with single object. the error says "no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘comp’ and ‘comp’)". Important code snippets are

```
class comp
{
    int a,b;
public:
    comp()
{
    a=b=1;
}
    comp(int,int);
    comp(comp &);
    comp operator+(comp &);
    operator int();
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"a= "<<a<<"b= "<<b<<endl;
    }
    comp& operator=(comp &);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, comp &c);
};


    comp::comp(comp & c)//copy constructor
    {
        a=c.a,b=c.b;
        cout<<"copy constructor called"<<endl;
    }
    comp comp::operator+(comp & c1)// overloaded '+' opreator
    {
        comp c;
        c.a=a+c1.a;
        c.b=b+c1.b;
        return c;
    }
    comp & comp::operator =(comp & c)// I tried with return type as void also
    {
         cout<<"in operator ="<<endl;
        a=c.a,b=c.b;
        return *this;
    }
int main()
{
    comp c1,c2(2,3),c3;
    c3=c2+c1;
    cout<<c3;
    comp c4=c3+c1;
    cout<<c4;
    int i=c4;
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try using const-ref? i.e., comp & comp::operator =(comp const & c) (same for your copy constructor)

Comment: `comp(comp &)` is not a copy-constructor. `comp(comp const&)` is. In the same way `comp& operator=(comp&)` is no the assignment operator, but something that will produce many headaches later.

Comment: Thank you Cechner, its working when I used const-ref. But I have another doubt in the line comp c4=c3+c1, copy constructor is not getting called instead default constructor is being called. Why is this happening so?

Answer (score 2):

Lets take this line

```
comp c4=c3+c1;
```

The `c3+c1` operation returns a temporary object. However, non-constant references can't bind to temporary objects, and your copy-constructor takes its argument as a non-constant reference.

The fix is simple, change the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator to take their arguments as constant references instead, e.g.

```
comp(const comp& c);
```

---

Note that using a non-constant reference argument in e.g. a copy-constructor still makes it possible to use it, you just have to pass actual non-temporary objects to it, like

```
comp c1;
comp c2 = c1;  // Should work with non-constant reference
```

Comment: yes , the statement comp c2=c1; is working with non-constant reference. now I changed to const comp& c. overloaded '=' is working fine but copy constructor is not being called for the statement comp c4=c3+c1;

Answer (score 0):

By default some copy operations are optimized. To make sure that no copy optimization is used you should use proper compiler flag. For gcc try to use: -no-eligible-constructors